# Ngram generation from word to character

Tags: java, nlp

How to generate ngram from a sequence of words in JAVA?

> string = 'McDonalds world'
>
> n=3

Output should be

> ['McD', 'cDo', 'Don', 'ona', 'nal', 'ald', 'lds','dsw','swo','wor','orl','rld']

Give some idea in Java, how to implement that.

Comment: Remove spaces between the words. Then, take a window size of the number of characters you want to output.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class NgramGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(generateNgrams("ABC", 3));
        System.out.println(generateNgrams("McDonalds world", 3));
        System.out.println(generateNgrams("Mc Donalds world", 3));
        System.out.println(generateNgrams("McDonalds ", 1));
        System.out.println(generateNgrams("M  ", 1));
        System.out.println(generateNgrams("M ", 1));
        System.out.println(generateNgrams(" ", 1));
        System.out.println(generateNgrams("", 1));
        System.out.println(generateNgrams(null, 1));
    }

    private static List<String> generateNgrams(String word, int ngram) {

        if (ngram == 0 || word == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        word = word.replace(" ", "");

        if (word.isEmpty()) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        if (ngram > word.length()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid word or n-gram");
        }

        List<String> ngrams = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= word.length() - ngram; i++) {
            ngrams.add(word.substring(i, i + ngram).trim());
        }
        return ngrams;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are new to StackOverflow. Please refrain from giving the answer immediately, especially to questions like this, since the OP did not post his/her attempt. By giving the answer immediately you are talking away the OP's chance to learn. Thank you.